# Matlab IMRECT backward compatibility

Tags: matlab, compatibility

I've writtend a GUI function in MATLAB R2009b which makes use of the IMRECT function. I need to make sure this GUI also works in MATLAB R2007b: since this release the IMRECT function has undergone extensive changes. I have two question:

1 - in the new (R2009b) IMRECT, a method GETCOLOR is defined which allows to get the color which was selected by the user using the scroll menu. Is there a way to mimic this behavior for the old (R2007b) function?

2 - in MATLAB R2009b I can use WAIT after using IMRECT as follows:

```
h = imrect(axhandle);
wait(h);
```

this allows to wait unitl the user as correctly placed his/her rectangle and has double click to confirm the choice. Is there anything analogous that can be used with IMRECT from R2007b?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need a workaround for both functions.

Here is one way to do it:

```
%# Create a figure and some points
fh = figure;plot(rand(10,1),rand(10,1),'.')
ah = gca;

%# this allows the user to place the rectangle. However, the code resumes
%# as soon as the rectangle has been drawn
rh = imrect(ah,[]);

%# Create a dialog to have the possibility to uiwait
wh = warndlg('Please close this dialog once you are done adjusting your rectangle');
uiwait(wh)

%# Get the color of the rectangle
rectKids = get(rh,'Children');
rectangleColor = get(rectKids(1),'Color');
```

You can use [verLessThan](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/verlessthan.html) to check for the Matlab version in order to get the proper functionality. However, if there are users who'll use the code both on 2007b and 2009b, I suggest you leave the dialog box in for everyone, so that they don't get confused when they switch.